# Cosmic drag and heat

Tags: cosmology, temperature

http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/universe-getting-hotter-09037.html

Basically the premise of this article is that the universe is restrained by heat and drag in the ether ("spacetime").

Is this disputed?

Comment: I read the article, You are asking   if your interpretation  ( this is not what the article says) is correct?

Answer (score 3):

The formation of a galaxy or a cluster of galaxies involves taking a large volume of gas and allowing gravity to pull it into a smaller volume. A consequence of this is that the gas becomes hotter as gravitational energy is turned into thermal energy. (e.g. the [Virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) suggests half the gravitational energy released goes into heating the gas).

What [Chiang et al. (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14650) have been able to do, is use the thermal [Sunyaev-Zeldovich effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunyaev%E2%80%93Zeldovich_effect), to measure the thermal energy density, or equivalently, the average temperature of the gas, at different redshifts and hence look-back times.

The thermal S-Z effect is caused by low energy photons in the cosmic microwave background (CMB) getting a boost in their energy via inverse Compton scattering from hot gas in collapsed structures in the universe. This results in small fluctuations in the CMB temperature that are correlated with the structures that can be seen in galaxy redshift surveys.

By measuring these correlations it is possible to infer the gas pressure and hence thermal energy density *as a function of redshift*.

The results suggest that the gas is cooler looking back to about half the age of the universe (by about a factor of 2-3 on average) than it is now. This appears to fit in with ideas about how large-scale structure in the universe grows and develops.